# How to add line numbers to stacktraces in UWP apps?

Tags: .net, uwp, stack-trace, pdb-files

My understanding is that it is not possible to deploy symbols to an UWP app. In the *.appxupload there is a file *.appxsym which contains *.pdb files. But this files will not deploy to the client on installation. Is this right?

Is there any tool that can add line numbers later to a stacktrace with the existing *.pdb files?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT It is not a question of how to debug debug with symbols. The question is how I can analyze a stacktrace that come from a customer from a deployed UWP application.

Comment: From the Stacktrace, we can usually find some clues about the crash point of the app, which in most scenarios will be a method entry point. But if the source codes of the app is not available, it is by most time not possible to locate the root cause of the crash.

Answer (score 1):

> How to add line numbers to stacktraces in UWP apps?

You could use `HockeyApp` to capture the exception call stack, exception message, exception type name, file name and line number which caused a crash in the app. For more detail please refer this [document](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/crash-reporting-for-uwp).

**Please note**: In order to symbolicate crashes for .NET UWP applications you need to upload symbol (*.pdb) files

Comment: I have never write from crash of the app. I means stacktraces in the log file of the application which will be printed for every error message. Most of the error messages will user input mistakes. But if such error has another cause then the customer can send the log file to the support. I does not expect that the app will completely crash.